# Python py pyfirmata code is showing the incorrect value

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

I write the following code to check the value of input pin but it never shows the digital value as input. I don't know what is wrong. Can any one explain it ?

```
from pyfirmata import ArduinoMega, util
board = ArduinoMega('COM3')

digital_0 = board.get_pin('d:30:i')
board.digital[9].write(1)
value= digital_0.read()
print value
```

The result is always :

```
>>> 
None
>>>
```

Comment: can you explain what this line does? - `digital_0 = board.get_pin('d:30:i')`  , I never used either arduino or python, but look cool to me ( that's robotics yes?)

Comment: yes it is robotics and this line is defining pin as digital input   @Coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`board.digital[9].write(1)` must be changed to `board.digital[30].write(1)`

Because you want to get information about pin 30, not 9.

Then you will get this error:

> Digital pin 30 is set up as an INPUT and can therefore not be written to

Solution:

```
digital_0 = board.get_pin('d:30:o')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wan not using pull-down resistor that is why it was giving the wrong value. This problem is solved long ago :)